# What would be most efficient way to parse string into a map?

Tags: java, parsing, csv, dictionary

The code I'm looking at make's a URL call that returns a string made up off points for plotting a chart.[14.1(point),1363649400(timestamp in UTC will be converted later)]

```
String = [14.1,1363649400],[14.4,1363650300],[14.6,1363651200],[15.1,1363652100],[14.3,1363653000],[14.2,1363653900],[14.8,1363654800]................
```

The best way seems to be to remove square brackets and then use String.split().

So wondering if anyone had better idea's on how to convert this string to a Map, say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take care of parsing and building the map. The map will also be sorted by timestamp.

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?),(.*?)\\]").matcher(input);
final Map<Long, Double> points = new TreeMap<>();
while (m.find()) 
  points.put(Long.parseLong(m.group(2), Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
points[] = string.substring(1, string.length()-1).split("],[");
```

which would result in an array of

```
"1,3", "3,4"
```

Comment: `"1,3", "3,4"` where it comes from?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov From input `"[1,3],[3,4]"`.

Comment: Its just an example output. ["1,3"],["3,4"] => "1,3"],["3,4" => "1,3", "3,4"

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I expected output for the OP's input :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to hold your data objects:

```
private static final class Data {

    private final BigDecimal point;
    private final Date date;

    public Data(final String point, final String date) {
        this.point = new BigDecimal(point);
        this.date = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" + "point=" + point + ", date=" + date + '}';
    }
}
```

Now parse the string using a regex pattern, building the `Data` objects as you go. I have used possessive matchers as the `String` is presumably quite long and you don't want the express engine to backtrack along it repeatedly trying to match.

The `Data` can, as here, even parse the individual `String`s to the real data types.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "[14.1,1363649400],[14.4,1363650300],[14.6,1363651200],[15.1,1363652100],[14.3,1363653000],[14.2,1363653900],[14.8,1363654800]";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^,]++),(\\d++)\\]");
    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
    final Collection<Data> datas = new LinkedList<Data>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        datas.add(new Data(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)));
    }
    for (final Data data : datas) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Data{point=14.1, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:29 GMT 1970}
Data{point=14.4, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:30 GMT 1970}
Data{point=14.6, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:31 GMT 1970}
Data{point=15.1, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:32 GMT 1970}
Data{point=14.3, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:33 GMT 1970}
Data{point=14.2, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:33 GMT 1970}
Data{point=14.8, date=Fri Jan 16 19:47:34 GMT 1970}
```

Obviously you can put those `Data` into a `Map` or `Set` or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression doesn't seem to be the best approach, at least to me. The performance of regex in java is, to be honest, really bad. I'd write a parser myself, which would only take `O(n)` n being the length of the string.

How I'd do it:

```
public void splitSequence(String str) {
                List<Double> lstPoint = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> lstTime = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] buf = new char[128];
    int i=0;
    boolean isPoint = true;
    for(Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if(c == ',') {
            if(isPoint) {
                lstPoint.add(new Double(new String(buf,0,i)));
                isPoint = false;
            }
            else {
                lstTime.add(Long.parseLong(new String(buf,0,i)));
                isPoint = true;
            }
            buf = new char[128];
            i=0;
        } else if(!(c == '[' || c == ']')) {
            buf [i++] = c;
        }
    }
    }
//usage
splitSequence("[14.1,1363649400],[14.4,1363650300],[14.6,1363651200],[15.1,1363652100],[14.3,1363653000],[14.2,1363653900],[14.8,1363654800]");
```

Comment: I think the performance of regex is solely dependant on how the regex is written - i.e. how much backtracking the engine has to do. If you write regex properly and there is little to no backtracking (using possessive matchers etc) then performance will also be O(n). If there are any irregularities in the input your two `List`s will become mis-aligned and the data will become corrupted.

Comment: Using DFA's O(n) is more than possible, it's actually easy. But is this how Java implements it? I'm not really sure, but I've heard that it is not... Like Einstein said, half knowledge is worse than not knowing at all.

Comment: No, Java is NFA. But using the possessive quantifier (e.g. ++ rather than +) prevents the engine from backtracking. Possessive quantifiers grab everything that matches and then don't give it back allowing for much faster parsing.

Comment: I did a quick microbench using the longest constant string java allows with both the methods, each run 10,000 times. Your method takes 911 microseconds (less than a millisecond) on average and mine takes 1219 microseconds on average. So your method is faster, just not by much. Your method running time comes down by 100 microseconds if you use a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @bmorris591 thanks for the benchmarks. It's kinda interesting that java's regex is actually that strong. But for my case there is a lot of room for improvement (like not calling new, linkedLists that are prebuffered...). But in the end, it really depends on the case, if you really need the 0.3-0.4 milliseconds, depends on that alone.